# Refactor class to inner class while updating imports

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

I have a class that I would like to make an inner class, is there a way to do that and update all imports like when moving a class using the `Refactor` menu option?

currently:

```
    class A

    class B
```

what I'd like to achieve:

```
    class A {
        class B
    }
```

Edit:
I'm using Kotlin, which doesn't have the `move to inner class` option while a Java class does.

Answer (score 1):

You may go to class B, put a caret on class name, then *Refactor* | *Move class*, in the opened menu select A class in ***make inner class of*** field:
[image]

All the imports from class B will be removed to A.

Comment: There is no such option for Kotlin data classes. There are only `To package` and `To file`options

Comment: See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-9834

Answer (score 1):

I simulated the refactoring with the following steps.

1. Rename `B` to `A_B` (or some other name that's unique in the project) using the [rename refactoring](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/rename-refactorings.html).
2. Make `A_B` an inner class of `A` (manually move the code)
3. Use ["search and replace"](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/finding-and-replacing-text-in-project.html#replace_search_string_in_project) in the project to replace `A_B` with `A.B`
4. Fix import statements by doing another search/replace for `import full.package.name.A.B` to `import full.package.name.A`

The first step makes it less likely that the subsequent search and replace steps break something.

If your project includes Java code, the last step may need some finessing since the import statement can end with a semicolon `;`.